# Is there a way to paste shortcuts in Ubuntu as in Windows?

Tags: rhythmbox, filelink, media-library

Paste shortcuts, or perhaps create a link to another folder from a folder, or any thing of the sort.

I need to do this because I want to crate a link from other directories to my music folder, so that Rhythmbox can update its libraries like that.
I am also asking if it is a good way for adding music to Rhythmbox's library. I am quite new to this, please pardon if the question meets the foolishness criteria. :|

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in Nautilus (the equivalent of Windows Explorer) within Ubuntu.

Let's say you want to make a shortcut of

```
/home/your_name/source_folder
```

inside another folder called

```
/home/you_name/dest_folder
```

**1. Drag and drop**

Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and **drag the source_folder** with the Left mouse button **into the dest_folder**.

**2. Right Click Menu**

Right click on the source_folder and choose **Make Link**. A new folder called **"Link to source_folder"** will be created in `/home/you_name/` and you can move it inside **dest_folder** and rename the link to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from the Termnial:

```
ln -s /home/your_name/source_folder /home/you_name/dest_folder
```

Answer (score 1):

Right click the folder you want to link to, select `Make Link`. A link to the that folder will be created, and you can copy it to the music folder, or wherever within the filesystem.

PS: Apologies, if it's not like in Windows, not sure how it's done there.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Mouse with 3 buttons (or a pressable mouse wheel) you can drag and drop the file/folder with the 3rd button pressed.
Alternatively, hold down the "Alt"-Key while dragging. A pop-up menu will give you options whether you want to link, move or copy.

(That is for Unity and Gnome. KDE might be different.)

EDIT:

I just played around a little. When you press "Shift+CTRL" while you drag, it will crate a link. The mouse pointer indicates which action will be taken (a small plus next to it means copy, a knot for a link)